# leer XLSX en C#

Tags: c#, excel

Para leer un archivo de excel estoy haciendo lo siguiente.

```
string excelpath = ("datos\\informe.xls");

string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseFilePath"] + excelpath;

ExcelWorkbook workbook = new ExcelWorkbook(filepath);
ExcelWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
```

Hasta aquí no tengo dudas.

Ahora quiero lo mismo pero para leer archivos XLSX. 
¿Sería suficiente hacer el .Format?

```
string excelpath = ("datos\\informe.xlsx");

string filepath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseFilePath"] + excelpath;

ExcelWorkbook workbook = new ExcelWorkbook(filepath);
workbook.Format = ExcelWorkbookFormat.Xlsx_2007;
ExcelWorksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
```

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, no hace falta que definas nada para leer un xlsx, se lee igual que un xls (al menos dentro de la librería `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`), se te está disparando alguna excepción o algo al intentar abrirlo?

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal confirmo con Juan, la librería interfiere y asume que estás leyendo un excel en el formato nuevo, no se necesita especificar el formato. Lo único malo es que necesitas tener instalado el paquete de Office para poder lograr esto. Es recomendable utilizar otro tipo de manejadores para evitar el tener que instalar Office en cada cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Tendrias que generar un archivo nuevo para cambiarle el formato y la extension, para eso usas el `SaveAs()`

[Workbook.SaveAs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas?view=vsto-2017)

entonces cuando tengas todo editado usarias

```
string baseFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseFilePath"];
string excelpath = @"datos\informe.xlsx";
string fileDestinationPath = Path.Combine(baseFilePath, excelpath );

excelWorkbook.SaveAs(fileDestinationPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value,
                       Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                       Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, 
                       Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Nota: define el using a `System.Reflection` para usar el `Missing.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Si usas sqlBulkCopy

Podes definir en webconfig:

```
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'" />
```

Luego en el codigo podes leer el archivo:
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

```
            //filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            //string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            //postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            string renamedFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString(("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_MM_ss")) + extension;
            filePath = path + renamedFile;
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);


            string conString = string.Empty;
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 and above.
                    conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
            }
```

con esto tenes el swicheo para los  dos tipos de extencion de archivos